# Write file RNFetchBlob overide files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I'm using rnFetch blob to create files like:

RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(uri, base64, "base64")

It works but sometimes I need to override that image.

As the [doc](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#encodingutf8--base64--ascii--uri-1) says:

writeFile API replaces content in the file, if you're going to append data to existing file[...]

But it crashes the image and create a 0byte image when i try to overide using again.
Anyone has passed by this?

Comment: How big is the base64, meaning how many number of characters??

Comment: If the base64 is too big, the best option is to use [writestream](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#writestreampathstring-encodingstringpromise) where data will be written in chunks in dedicated intervals of time.